# Как сделать фон именно под текстом, не покрывая пространство между строк

Tags: html, css

Как сделать фон именно под текстом, не покрывая пространство между строк?
Нужно сделать вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в итоге получается, что заливает весь фон,вот сам код собственно:

```css
#block-for-slider ul li h2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 160px;
    top:140px; 
    font-size: 4.375em;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ffea00;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Перерыл весь инет решения найти не могу буду премного благодарен.

---

Всё спасибо наконец-то дошло, просто видимо очень долго пытался и запутался в конец, всем спасибо.
Поставил span с бэкграундом, и line-height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну как вариант)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.container__inner {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.container__text {
  background: #ffeb00;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}

.container__text:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__inner">
    <div class="container__text">Lorem ipsum</div>

    <div class="container__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.highlighted {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  outline: gray solid 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<span class="highlighted">Пример построчно закрашенного<br>текста</span>
```

Перенос строк внутри `<span>` поддерживается. Чтобы сделать видимость выделения "построчно", добавьте свойство `line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

Поместите каждую строку Вашего текста в тег `<span>.` Потом добавьте этому тегу css-свойство: `background-color: yellow;`

Comment: Это не помогло возможно вы меня не правильно поняли, мне нужно что бы между строк не было бэкграунда, что бы окрашено все было только вокруг строк как на картинке которую я прикрепил,

Answer (score 0):

Всё что нужно, это использовать для текста `display: inline`, а расстояние полученных "блоков" подгонять при помощи `line-height`

```css
h1 {
  display: inline;
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem ipsum.<br>Consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
```